# php Failed to Upload to Temp folder

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm stuck at how to get this working!

I have a server (Ubuntu 14.04) PHP 5.6, I'm using a script which contains an admin panel I created categories and upload images on it.

I'm facing a permissions issues I tried to set the permissions to apache user www-data.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     6083 Jul 13 14:16 add_category.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2914 Jul 13 00:55 add_wallpaper_animation.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     4228 Jul 13 00:55 add_wallpaper.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     7380 Jul 13 00:55 api.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     1121 Jul 13 00:55 api_urls.php
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 13 00:55 assets
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 13 14:22 categories
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     3811 Jul 13 00:55 edit_wallpaper_animation.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     5183 Jul 13 00:55 edit_wallpaper.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data        4 Jul 13 14:23 file.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2069 Jul 13 00:55 home.php
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 13 02:32 images
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 13 00:55 includes
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2968 Jul 13 00:55 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 13 00:55 language
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data      917 Jul 13 00:55 login_db.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data      121 Jul 13 00:55 logout.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     3874 Jul 13 00:55 manage_category.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     4189 Jul 13 00:55 manage_wallpaper_animation.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     4437 Jul 13 00:55 manage_wallpaper.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     3262 Jul 13 00:55 pagination.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 37121978 Jul 13 00:55 php_web_services.zip
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     5121 Jul 13 00:55 profile.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data    14315 Jul 13 00:55 settings.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data       41 Jul 13 14:22 test.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     3086 Jul 13 00:55 thumbnail_images.class.php
```

the add_category.php always fails. It returns no Error but it returns a 500 status code!

the add_category php code that fails:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_GET['add']))
    {
    
       $category_image=rand(0,99999)."_".$_FILES['category_image']['name'];
       
       //Main Image
       $tpath1='images/'.$category_image; 
       
       $pic1=compress_image($_FILES["category_image"]["name"], $tpath1, 80);

        //Thumb Image 
       $thumbpath='images/thumbs/'.$category_image;     
       $thumb_pic1=create_thumb_image($tpath1,$thumbpath,'200','200');   

          
       $data = array( 
                'category_name'  =>  $_POST['category_name'],
               'category_image'  =>  $category_image
                );      

        $qry = Insert('tbl_category',$data);    

        $cat_id=mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
        
      

       if(!is_dir('categories/'.$cat_id))
       {
    
            mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id, 0777);

            mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id.'/thumbs', 0777);
       }            

        $_SESSION['msg']="10";
 
        header( "Location:manage_category.php");
        exit;   

         
        
    }
```

1. I tried to create a simple php file (test.php) contains:

```
    <?php
    
    mkdir("categories/test",0700);
    ?>
```

it works perfectly but still the add_category.php fails!

I'm really stuck at this can you help me out?

EDIT:

I thought that the file has no permissions to use the temp folder so I changed the php.ini upload_tmp_dir to another path that can be accessed by add_category.php, but it still fails!

- I tried to give the permission also to /tmp folder and make it accessible by www-data user but it still didn't work

Comment: If you get a 500 error, check your server log for the reason.

Comment: i have no error at /var/log/apache2

Comment: the page load perfectly even that i received a 500 status code

Comment: Your last comment suggests that the 500 code is not 'real' - something is setting 500 even when no error has occurred. Check the code path in a debugger?

Comment: @rivimey the code fails at `$pic1=compress_image($_FILES["category_image"]["name"], $tpath1, 80);`

Comment: i'm a bit sure that the error is on `$pic1=compress_image($_FILES["category_image"]["tmp_name"], $tpath1, 80);` like the file cannot access the temp folder